# How to Structure A Simple EntityStore

Tags: entity

I have modified a simple example from the documentation:

```
store = EntityStore[
  "t" -> <|"Entities" -> <|"e1" -> <|"p1" -> 17|>, 
      "e2" -> <|"p2" -> 288|>|>|>];
EntityRegister[store];
Entity["t", "e1"]["Properties"]
```

In this modified example, entity e1 only has property p1, while entity e2 only has property p2.  However, when you query the properties for each entity, both properties p1 and p2 are listed.

Is there a way to structure the store so that only property p1 shows for entity e1 and only property p2 shows for entity e2?